# How to assign the contents of multiple files to different classes attributes through just one loop?

Tags: c++

I have three different text files called *a.txt*, *b.txt* and *c.txt* to be taken from the command line. I have also three classes called *class A*, *class B* and *class C* each of which corresponds to each of those files. For instance, "a.txt" contains:

```
12 title1
15 title2
20 title3
```

where the first column is the "id" and the second one is the title(in each row there is a space between the id and the title). Corresponds to this file is Class A which its header file is like:

```cpp
class A {
public:
    A();

    // the id doesn't need to be int
    A(const string &id, const string &title);

    void setId(const string &id);

    void setTitle(const string &title);

private:
    string id_;
    string title_;
};
```

The program should take the arguments (which are the files) from command line, read the contents of each file and extracts its content to assign the variables of the corresponding class. Following the above example, the program through `setID` should assign "12" to `a1.id_` and through `setTitle` assign "title1" to `a1.title_` and the same for the other two instances. Is it possible to do the all mentioned jobs with all of files and the classes through just one **efficient** loop? In either case (if possible or not possible) what is the suggested solution?

**Edit**
Creating so many differently-named variables for each class is not cost effective at all

Comment: Use a container such as `std::vector<A>` and just `push_back` to create new instances of `A`.  Also, why just 3 instances of `A`?  What if there were 5? 10? 800?  I'm sure you wouldn't want to create 5, 10, or 800 different variables.

Comment: Hint: it's hard to loop `A a1; A a2; A a3;` but it is easy to loop `A a[3]` or `std::array<A,3>`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That's right, creating so many instances doesn't make sence. I edited the question.

Comment: @Bsh *creating so many instances doesn't make sence* -- You mean creating so many differently-named variables -- you will be typing forever.  However, creating many different *instances* is perfectly ok in this scenario, but to do that, use a container of some sort, where the instance is retrieved using an index.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will store all the data in a container. And for this task, we need a dynamic container, which can grow. A `std::vector` is the way to go.

To make this code efficient, we will overwrite the inserter and extractor operator of your class A. The inserter will simply insert the ID and the Title into the output stream. Easy to understand.

The extractor is slightly more complicated, but also easy to understand. We first extract the id, with a standard ">>" operation. Then we read the rest of the line with `std::getline` because the title may contain blanks. That would be a delimiter for the ">>" operator. Please note, the `std::getline` will read leading/trailing blanks. Maybe you need to "trim" your Title-string.

In main, we simply loop through the command line arguments and open the file for each argument. If it could be opened, the we use `std::copy` to copy all lines of the file, so the complete content, into our `std::vector` of type A.

The `std::istream_terator` will call the overwritten extractor operator of our A-class, line for line, until the file is at the end. The `std::back_inserter` will "push_back" the read A instances into the vector.

At the end of main, we show the complete content of the A-vector.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

class A {
public:
    // Constructors
    A() : id_(), title_() {}
    A(const std::string& id, const std::string& title) : id_(id), title_(title) {}

    // Setters
    void setId(const std::string& id) { id_ = id; }
    void setTitle(const std::string& title) { title_ = title; }

    // Overwrite extractor for easier reading
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, A& a) {
        if (std::string id{}, title{}; is >> id && getline(is, title)) {
            a.id_ = id; a.title_ = title;
        }
        return is;
    }
    // Overwrite inserter for easier writing
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const A& a) {
        return os << "Id: " << std::setw(5) << a.id_ << "   Title: " << a.title_ << "\n";
    }
private:
    std::string id_{};
    std::string title_{};
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    // Here we will store all read data
    std::vector<A> data{};

    // Work on all command line arguments
    for (size_t fileNumber = 1; fileNumber < argc; ++fileNumber) {

        // Open the corresponding file and check, if it is open
        if (std::ifstream ifs(argv[fileNumber]); ifs) {

            // Copy all data from this file into the class and the vector 
            std::copy(std::istream_iterator<A>(ifs), {}, std::back_inserter(data));
        }
    }

    // Show the result on the screen
    std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<A>(std::cout));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer. In the default constructor `A() : id_(), title_() {}`, isn't it better to initialise each attribute with `""`?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But the default constructor for the ````std::string````, which is called with ````title_()```` will do that for us. So, your requirements are fulfilled.